# shielded from the crucible of human reason

Tags: word-usage

Does "crucible" here mean "a place or situation in which people or ideas are tested severely, often creating something new or exciting in the process" (Oxford Dicts)?

> The End of Faith articulates the dangers and absurdities of organized religion so fiercely and so fearlessly that I felt relieved as I read it, vindicated, almost personally understood… Harris writes what a sizable number of us think, but few are willing to say in contemporary America… This is an important book, on a topic that, for all its inherent difficulty and divisiveness, should not be **shielded from the crucible of human reason**.

Source: [The New York Times Book Review](https://samharris.org/books/the-end-of-faith/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crucible (noun) from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crucible)

- a severe test
- a place or situation in which concentrated forces interact to cause
  or influence change or development

The "**crucible of human reason**" is referring to people critically thinking about and judging the topic discussed in the book, basically a "**a place or situation in which people or ideas are tested severely**" as you already assumed.